# Dynamic callback endpoints with cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When a user triggers a function there’s a POST request going away to a partner. Within the body I need to include a unique endpoint callbackURL with an Id so they can send me status updates linked with a specific user. How can I accomplish that? I know how to setup static endpoints, but not create new ones for every request.

Comment: What is your exact problem? How to include the id in the body of the POST request that your Cloud Function issues? OR, how to set a up an endpoint to be called through the callbackURLs?

Comment: Why do you need a whole new endpoint for every request?  Can you not use the existing URL for a deployed function?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I need help with creating a callbackURL (like endpoint/<id>/callback), where Id is unique for every new post request. So when receiving the response I know which status update belongs to a specific user.

Comment: @DougStevenson using an existing URL make it impossible to distinguish what status update belongs to the correct user.

Comment: HTTP offers ways to pass parameters to a function.  That's how the callback can identify itself uniquely to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug said in his comment above, you don't need a new URL (i.e. a new endpoint) for each different `id`. You can deploy only one [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) (which exposes one endpoint) and, in the Cloud Function, you extract the value of `id` from the [`Request`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) object with its [`originalUrl`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl) property, as follows:

```
exports.myWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const urlArray = req.originalUrl.split('/');

    console.log(urlArray);
    console.log(urlArray[1]);

    const id = urlArray[1]; 
    //Do whatever you need with id
    //.....

    //If you want to test that it works with a browser, you can send it back as a response to the browser
    res.send(urlArray[1]);

});
```

You then call this Cloud Function with the following URI:

https://us-central1-yourprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/myWebhook/id/callback

---

Note that it is also possible to extract values from the Request body, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0#read_values_from_the_request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out @RenaudTarnec. I have managed to do exactly what you described earlier (+ extracting body). Here's exactly where the problem arises: exporting this cloud functions gives me the static url:

https://us-central1-yourprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/myWebhook/

And including that URL in the POST body request makes no sense because there's no id attached that the partner server can use. What you described above, with the /id/callback is exactly what I need - can I just add that to the url and it will work?

Thanks!

Comment: «Can add that after the url and it will work»: yes it will. Just give try calling it with a browser. With https://us-central1-yourprojectname.cloudfunctions.net/myWebhook/id/callback as shown in my answer I add /id/callback at the end of the CF URL.